# webscraping google maps with pupeeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping

I want to get the data of a specific search in the proximity of my house. But I can't make the scroller of the search box of google maps to load fully to be able to get the whole data.

Because of that, I tried to make this section to load, but I don't know how to do it:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BZLp.png)

```
const pup = require("puppeteer");
const { scrollPageToBottom } = require("puppeteer-autoscroll-down");
const fs = require("fs");
const url = "https://www.google.com/maps/";
const searchFor = "eletricista";

/* let c = 1;
const list = []; */

const scrapeInfiniteScrollItems = async (page) => {
  while (true) {
    previousHeight = await page.evaluate(`document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > div').scrollHeight`);
    await page.evaluate(`window.scrollTo(0, document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > div').scrollHeight)`);
    await page.waitForFunction(`document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > div').scrollHeight > ${previousHeight}`);
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
  }
};


(async () => {
  const browser = await pup.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  console.log("Iniciei!");

  await page.goto(url);
  console.log("Fui para a URL!");

  await page.waitForSelector("#searchboxinput");

  await page.type("#searchboxinput", searchFor);

  await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.click("#searchbox-searchbutton"),
  ]);


  await scrapeInfiniteScrollItems(page);

  const links = await page.$$eval(".ecceSd > div > div > div > a", (el) =>
    el.map((link) => link.href)
  );

  console.log(links);

  await page.waitForTimeout(20000);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

What should I change to be able to get the holde data?
I tried to use evaluate to get the div container that has all the search results data, but i can't do it.